# WiFi is disabled by hardware switch on toshiba tecra A9

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04, wifi-hardware-switch

I have this annoying problem that bugs several Ubuntu laptop users: from time to time my WiFi drops and I got the message 'WiFi is disabled by hardware switch' even though it is on (there are two methods on my laptop: <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>f8</kbd> & a physical switch on the front).

Even stranger is that I also cannot get a connection when inserting a USB dongle. It doesn't turns on or if it does, it gets also the same message.

I already tried `rfkill unblock all` , to no avail.
This is the output from `rfkill list`:

```
0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

output from `sudo lshw -class network`:

```
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: PRO/Wireless 4965 AG or AGN [Kedron] Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 61
       serial: 00:1f:3b:2c:87:99
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwl4965 driverversion=4.4.0-36-generic firmware=228.61.2.24 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:30 memory:ff8fe000-ff8fffff
```

ps:
I also tried to restart the network with `sudo service network-manager restart`
, but no succes either

**Update:** I started having this issue when putting the laptop on resume.
Also, when I have this problem, I cannot get WiFi working the other OS (windows vista) on the laptop either. So possibly this is a hw/bios issue? 
fyi, I post pictures from the bios:

page 1
[image: page 1]
page 2
[image: page 2]

Comment: Could  you update your question tags with the Ubuntu version you are using, ie 14.04 or 16.04, etc? Also has this problem always been there or did it start occurring after a system update/upgrade?

Comment: This problem has'nt occured since a couple of weeks anymore. I suspect it's hardware related (laptop +- 7 years old). I'll mark this question as solved.

Comment: Marking the question as solved is certainly one solution. Another way is to delete your answer and then delete your question... Either way works to close the question but the second method means others won't be lead down the wrong path when searching questions in AskUbuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem seems to happen from time to time and dissapears automatically. I suspect it's due to old hardware (laptop +- 7 years old) so maybe the wifi card (which is soldered on the mb unfortunately) is malfunctioning.